# Audio/Video Calling using Chrome - Web RTC

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, windows-7, signalr, webrtc

From various article i came to know that Windows 7 does not supports web sockets. please correct me if i am wrong

Lets say my client is using Windows 7 OS and Chrome for audio/video calling.

Server is built on Nodejs/SignalR.

I would like to know whether Audio/Video calls are supported on Windows 7. How to check whether two clients are connected?

Currently i am trying audio calling same network.

Thanks,
Krishna

Comment: Websocket support is not really dependent on the OS. Its the browsers job to implement it, and its implemented over standard TCP sockets, which all OS's support.

Comment: You can test webRTC capabilities via this demo -  http://www.webrtc.org/demo works fine for me on Windows 7 Chrome

Comment: What "articles" are you referencing? WebSockets are implemented in the Browsers(Chrome, Firefox, and IE). You could create your own WebSocket server(This is what SignalR uses in `.NET`). It seems that you are missing the basics of what WebRTC is and should probably read through a couple more tutorials.

Comment: Yes i have mix up. Do i need to have stun server when both the clients are in same network/domain?

Comment: No, there is no need for an ICE server if they are both behind the same NAT.

Answer (score 0):

As comments state, the web browser has its own implementation of websockets. But this is when talking about client side.

Your information that Windows 7 don't support websocket may have to do with the server side and the version of IIS that comes with Windows 7.
The Websocket support was not introduced until IIS 8.0 and the version that comes with Windows 7 is IIS 7.5. You might be able to upgrade to IIS 8.0 to get the Websocket feature. But all this problems related to IIS is invalid if you already decided to use node.js because then you will probably take care of all server side signaling there.